# Why does VTEncoderXPCService take up all my cpu?

Tags: cpu

2010 Macbook Pro. Pretty frequently, my mac will spend over 100% cpu on VTEncoderXPCService. It causes the fan to spin up and it causes the computer to get hot.

```
ps -ef | grep -i vtencoder
```

shows

```
01   879     1   0 Mon10PM ??       261:54.85 /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/VTEncoderXPCService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/VTEncoderXPCService
```

which doesn't shed much light on the situation for me.

I'm not doing anything with video when this happens, either.

Any thoughts on what this is doing and/or how I can get it to not heat up my laptop so much?

Comment: I'm running into this in 2019 on my Mac Pro. Noticed tons of lag when recording my screen for making tutorials after upgrading to 10.15.3. Researching now. My issue is not related to Photos as it recurs with a clean install on 10.11.6 El Capitan. I'm going to try that PRAM stuff next.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be related to pulling movies out of Photos.  I had a large movie I was trying to take out of photos to a folder and move to an external drive.  This process was using over 300% of CPU for several minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I found some answers in a different thread:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7303110?start=0&tstart=0

"It's 100% Photos. After reading all the responses I went digging in Photos myself. In my case, I had Photos connecting to iCloud Photo Library in preferences.

The second I removed this connection, VTEncoderXPCService was virtually gone."

I deselected iPhotos in the iCloud management window, and it went away.  (Before, I would quit or force quite VTEncoderXPCService and it would just come back.)  So far, so good.

Comment: i closed photos, it continued, photos are just ONE of the users of the VideoToolbox (VT)

Answer (score 2):

I run into this with the Photos app open, usually when it's syncing media with iCloud. It's especially bad when the sync fails somehow. If you're able to get it to reproduce consistently, maybe send over some information to http://bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but it's the first thing that comes up in the Google machine, so throwing this out there for those it will help.
Teams running on a remote system connected via RDP (MS Remote Desktop) appears to offload the video processing to the client as well.  So, I typically connect audio through my phone, but if I start screen sharing from a Teams meeting within the RDP session VTEncoderXPCService will jump up (50-60% cpu utilization) and stay that way until I stop screen sharing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here, I got this going when Photos app is exporting pics to a slow drive, my USB memory stick. No issue as it disappeared as soon as the export was done.

Answer (score 0):

deactivate some options of the automatic iCloud functions - look in the photos options! there you find your "key". try one after another.

Comment: Can you explain why this will help, and which specific one to disable?

Answer (score 0):

After days of struggling, I find the real culprit is Microsoft Teams!

After conference call there will be a vtencoderxpcservice process takes up at least 1G memory.

Kill teams will solve the issue of vtencoderxpcservice keeps generated.